# How to interface LDR with microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, adc, interface, ldr

I need to interface an LDR with a microcontroller.

While searching for some circuit ideas on the internet, I came across two different ideas:

- One was using a voltage divider circuit with another resistor and input that into the ADC port of a microcontroller.
- Another was to couple the LDR to ground via small capacitor and connect the other end directly to a microcontroller. (I am not sure how this works?)

  For example:

  [image: schematic for measuring light using LDR without an ADC]

  <sub>Image source: [Measuring Light on a PIC 16F62x from Robot Builder](http://web.archive.org/web/20130828081343/http://www.robotbuilder.co.uk/Resources/Articles/149.aspx)</sub>

  > The PIC 16F62X series is a pin-compatible upgrade to the old F84 offering lots of extra internal goodies such as timers, a USART and a couple of comparators. There are no analogue to digital converters (ADC) as such but it is a simple job to use a comparator, a timer and a few lines of software to make one.

Which one is more accurate?

Comment: Can you provide resource (scheme) for the second circuit.

Comment: accurate in what sense? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: +1 on both above, but go option 1 if you have an ADC available. Very likely more accurate and much easier to understand / program.

Comment: @miceuz accurate for sun angle measurement.

Comment: http://www.robotbuilder.co.uk/Resources/Articles/149.aspx  @aiao

Comment: The above original link to `robotbuilder.co.uk` no longer works, so I have added a working link to the Web Archive into the question, as well as the schematic from that page. The details of the technique are described on that page.

Answer (score 5):

This is very simple:

[image]

Since both the voltage into the A/D input and the A/D's measuring range is relative to the PWR voltage, the PWR voltage cancels out.  The A/D pin voltage will be non-linear with light intensity.  Make R2 the value R1 has in the center of its range or where you want the most resolution.

Comment: @gopal - Just to add a little something: when I'm using a high-ish impedance sensor like this, I like to add a little capacitor (10nF - 100nF) between the A/D input and GND. This helps to charge the ADC's sample and hold capacitor more reliably, and also acts as a simple low pass filter. You'll get a better signal/noise ratio this way.